# More understandable explanation for Cat-Rabbit-Dog quiz

Tags: education

This is a quiz from Brilliant.org Algebra Fundamentals courses.

**Quiz:**
[image]
At Step 40, how many cats will there be in the 7th row?

**Answer:** 14

Explanation given by Brilliant.org is not clear to me so if someone can give a better explanation it will be helpful.

**Explanation by Brilliant.org**

> In rows where dividing by 3 has a remainder of 1, the pattern is
> cat-rabbit-dog.
>
> 7 when divided by 3 has a remainder of 1, so cats occur at 1, 4, 7,
> etc., i.e. at points where dividing by 3 has a remainder of 1.
>
> In step 40, the grid is 40 columns wide. The full cat-rabbit-dog
> pattern happens for $39\div 3=13$ times, but since the pattern
> at row 7 starts with a cat, column 40 has one extra cat. So there are
> $13 + 1 = 14$ cats.
>
> Note: A more compact way of saying "dividing $x$ by 3 has a remainder
> of 1" is $x \mod 3 = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading all the answers I able to understand more and here is my simple explanation.

- Its a sequence.
- 1<sup>st</sup> row and 4<sup>th</sup> row were same in Step *4*,
  so the pattern is same in every 3<sup>rd</sup> row,
  pattern in 1<sup>st</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> row is *Cat*-Rabbit-Dog-*Cat*-Rabbit-Dog-...
- In Step *n* we have *n*<sup>2</sup> animals and *n* animals in each row.
- Question is, in Step *40* how many cats are in row 7<sup>th</sup>?
- In Step *40* each row has 40 animals.[image]

Comment: This is a great explanation!  You might enjoy reading chapter 0 if "an illustrated theory of numbers" by marty Weissman if you enjoyed this puzzle.  The whole book is great, but that chapter is free on his website, and has many more problems like this one.

Answer (score 2):

In Step 40, there will be $40$ rows each containing $40$ animals. In each row, each group of three consecutive animals consists of one of each type. You can separate the seventh row into the first animal followed by $13$ groups of three. The $13$ groups of three will contain $13$ cats, so the answer will be $14$ if the first animal in the seventh row is another cat, and $13$ otherwise.

Counting down the first column, we see that the first, fourth, seventh, etc. (going up by $3$ each time) are cats. So the answer is $14$, because there is an extra cat at the start of the $7$th row.

What the explanation is trying to add is that you would get the same answer if the row was changed to any other number in the sequence $1,4,7,...$ (but no bigger than $40$). These numbers are the numbers that leave a remainder $1$ when divided by $3$. Other rows - those whose position divides exactly by $3$ or leaves remainder $2$ - will not have a cat at the start, so would have $13$ cats.

Answer (score 2):

It strikes me that this is a case where talking about division and remainders clouds the issue. I would explain things as follows:

Every third row is identical, so the seventh row is the same as the fourth is the same as the first.

At the fortieth step, the first row will have $13$ groups of three (cat, rabbit, dog) and one extra cat, for a total of $14$ cats. So the seventh row will also have $14$ cats.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, in step $n$, there is an animal in position $(r,c)$ iff $1\le r,c\le n$, and that animal is a cat iff $r+c\equiv 2\pmod 3$. So for $n=40$ and $r=7$, we want to find the number of $c$ with $1\le c\le 40$ and $7+c\equiv 2\pmod 3$. Those $c$ have the form $c=1+3k$ where $k$ is allowed to range from $0$ (making $c=1$) up to $13$ (making $c=40$).  So there are $$14$$ valid choices for $k$.